# How did we classify the finite simple groups when we haven't classified the primes?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

Why was the classification of the finite non-abelian simple groups "easier" (!!) than the classification of the finite abelian simple groups [the prime numbers], which still doesn't exist?

(Does it? There are infeasible algorithms for generating a complete irredundant list of prime numbers, but then it's not that hard to come up with an infeasible algorithm to "classify" all finite simple groups the same way.. construct each group and test for simplicity, only different is you need to then check isomorphism with other groups of same order to eliminate duplicates, but there's an infeasible algorithm for that too..)

And actually, what is the mathematical meaning of "classification"? Since the "classification" of non-abelian finite simple groups doesn't actually give a complete irredundant list (like the way, say, the classification of closed surfaces does), since 13 of the families of Lie type are indexed by prime numbers.

Comment: This is a matter of paying attention to what is given. For instance, any group of prime order is cyclic. Here I am not suggesting that I know all the primes, the statement is just "given" |G|=p and p prime then we have this property.

Comment: what do you mean by classification of primes?finite abelian simple groups are of prime order...converse is also true....one can very easily prove these .....It has nothing to do "classification of primes"

Comment: What do you mean by "classify the primes"? That seems like a nonsense phrase to me. The primes are "classified" by their definition.

Comment: @Potato Well, I have a feasible method to list the finite non-abelian simple groups, conditional upon being able to list the finite abelian simple groups, which are exactly the prime numbers. But there is no feasible way to list the prime numbers. Why is that so much harder?

Comment: @user235670 If you definite "classify" to mean "list them all," then of course you can't classify the primes. There are infinitely many of them, which makes them hard to list exhaustively...

Comment: @Potato: Feasibly computible bijection with the natural numbers?

Comment: @user235670 What do you mean by feasibly computable? If you give me a natural number $n$, I can give you a very simple algorithm for finding the $n$th prime number.

Comment: @Potato: Easy to describe but slow. I can do something similar for the finite simple groups -- less easy, but not that hard, certainly not nearly as hard as the classification theorem for finite simple groups.

Comment: You are confused. You claim that « the "classification" of non-abelian finite simple groups doesn't actually give a complete irredundant list»: if you know this for certain, you should write it down in a paper very soon and publish it for it would be an epoch making result...

Comment: Two things. First, my group theory knowledge is terrible, but the algorithm you indicate depends on being able to (a) enumerate all finite groups of a given order and (b) test them for simplicity. I suspect these are very hard problems for which algorithms may not exist. I would be interested to learn otherwise.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : it does so conditionally: you need to have a complete irredundant list of prime numbers.

Comment: Second, I suppose you can take "classify" to mean "come up with a satisfactory characterization." You aren't going to be able to characterize prime numbers in a more satisfactory way than their definition. But for finite simple groups, a much better description exists than their definition.

Comment: As I said, you are confused. You are not understanding what classification means in this context.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Yes, this seems to be the essential point of confusion. However, I confess a precise definition does not readily come to mind. Perhaps you could help provide our asker with a better understanding of this concept?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: That is correct, I am not understanding what classification means!

Comment: Just as we allow for factorials in what we call «closed form formulas» we allow primes in classifications — indeed, we allow anything «of a lower level» than the objects we are trying to classify (and what is lower level in this sense is a social decision). An immensely simpler classification is that of finite fields: the fact that it is computationally hard to find primes is absolutely irrelevant to the simple claim that there is a bijection between the set of pairs $(p,r)$ with $p$ a prime and $r$ a positive integers and the set of isomorphism classes of finite fields.

Comment: A classiffication is simply a bijection between two sets, preferably one of which has elements which are felt to be complicated to distinguish and/or construct and/or whatever, and the other of which has opposite characeristics.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Excellent! I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thanks for patient explanation and for the finite field example, this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The finite abelian simple groups are exactly $\mathbb Z / p\mathbb Z$ for $p$ a prime. If we want to classify finite simple groups then once we've put all of these groups in one class we are done with the abelian finite simple groups and we move on. We don't need to understand the primes to know that these are all the abelian finite simple groups.

Comment: @goblin, that is not a fair description of what the classification does. In the context of the classification theorem, the classification of the abelian simple groups is so trivial that anyone minimally fluent in the theory can do it in his sleep, so absolutely no emphasis is put on it. But simple-group-classifiers certainly do not «lump them all in a single basket»...

Comment: I meean precisely what I wrote. It is a bit absurd to claim that the classification of simple groups does not distinguish the abelian ones! That in most circumstances the corresponding detail is not included in the statements of the theorem is simply because that part of the result is of so minuscule interest in context that it is not worth it. But rest assured that th classification of simple groups **depends** in some way or another on the «detailed» classification of the simple abelian ones, for example...

Comment: i find that a rather extremely silly position.

Comment: This isn't worth my time.

Comment: @goblin, It is your prerogative to delete the three or four comments to which my comments above replied, of course. It is also rather distasteful.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, don't message me.

Comment: @goblin, *that*, on the other hand, is not your prerogative.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps someone has already mentioned this in the comments, but it should be pointed out that even the statement of the classification of finite nonabelian simple groups is heavily dependent on the classification of primes, because the groups of Lie type, which constitute the vast majority of the finite simple groups, all have an arbitrary prime power as a parameter.